# Como atualizar a página e para de atualizar?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou fazendo o seguinte código:

```
    if(xhr.status == 200){

      console.log(xhr.responseText);
      window.location.reload();

    }
```

só que quando faço isso, parece que ele entra num loop eterno e trava meu servidor. Como eu faço para ele atualizar a página só uma vez e parar?

Comment: Sim, porque o loop está atrapalhando

Comment: O responseText serve só pra me mostrar os dados que estou recebendo. Não preciso executar nenhuma função. Até vou tirar do código depois..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `document.referrer` e comparar com a URL atual: se for diferente executa o reload, se não, não faz nada:

```
if(document.referrer != location.href){   
   window.location.reload();
}
```

> **Problema:** se a página for atualizada com F5 ou com o botão de atualizar do navegador, o `referrer` pega a URL atual feito pelo `.reload()` e o `window.location.reload();` não será executado.